# Unable to enter content into popup contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, popupwindow

I have one problem that dont know how to fix. I working on custom mod for Job Application plugin, and in contact form wanted to insert option customer to be contacted via email. So i used WPForms plugin combined with PopupBuilder plugin to show contact for from WPForms. i inserted into php template file in this way, followed [developers](https://supsystic.com/documentation/open-popup-click/).

```
<div class="klasa">
<a href="<php echo do_shortcode('[sg_popup id=2]')?>">Enviar Mail</a>
</div>
```

but when click on button redirect me to 404 error. How to make this to show into popup and contact form to be usable. Class `klasa` is using just for styling the button, nothing more. [Link](https://www.asistesocial.es/resume/victoria-hlta9gy-auxiliar-de-enfermeria-vizcaya) where issue is present. Just press green contacto button.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed php tag, use

```
"<?php" instead of "<php"
<div class="klasa">
 <a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[sg_popup id=2]')?>">Enviar Mail</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that now is opening form automatically, and i want to opening on click on button inside form.. Check my link in first post to see how appear now.